# TFileStream и огромные файлы: не работают Read и Seek

Tags: delphi, файлы, filestream

Потребовалось поработать с огромными файлами (размер более 300 Гб) через TFileStream.

```
var
  fa: TFileStream;

fa:=TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenReadWrite, fmShareExclusive);
```

Всё в порядке, объект и handle создаются, но:
`fa.Size` возвращает `0`, `fa.Seek` с любыми параметрами `-1`, работа с `fa.Position` тоже безуспешна, попытка читать через `fa.Read` возвращает пустой буфер. При этом никаких ошибок. Компиляция - 64-битная.

Попытка вызова конструктора с другими параметрами ничего не даёт. При этом файлы меньших размеров работают нормально. В документации как таковых ограничений не нашёл.

Куда копать?

Опробованные версии Delphi: 10.1 (у меня), 11 (у коллеги).

Comment: а после, например, вызова `Seek(ххх, TSeekOrigin.soBeginning)` что скажет raiseLastOSError? Судя по коду - внутри Seek напрямую вызывается winapi, так что код ошибки не успеет чем-то перекрыться

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, версию Delphi

Comment: @ГерманБорисов уточнил в вопросе

Comment: @kami Выдала "A call to OS function failed"

Comment: А через CreateFile и Set/GetFilePointer с этим файлом получается работать?

Comment: можно проверить альтернативы - [BufferedStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639531/buffered-files-for-faster-disk-access/5639712#5639712) и GPHugeFile [отсюда, видимо](https://github.com/gabr42/GpDelphiUnits)

Comment: @MBo Буду проверять. Учитывая, что файлы данных "толстеют" на глазах, надо искать рабочее решение.

Comment: Попробуйте включить компиляцию с отладочными системными модулями и по шагам пройти вызовы Seek и Read (через F7) и посмотреть где затык. Там небольшие процедуры с вызовами WinAPI.

Comment: `Учитывая, что файлы данных "толстеют" на глазах` А разбиение на множество мелких или база данных не подойдёт?

Comment: @MBo Увы, базы данных - только для нас. Файл - универсален: для прибора, для клиента/партнера/клиники, даже для облака. Разбивать для некоторых задач можно, но их список узок.

Comment: @Alekcvp Проходил. Ошибок явных не высвечивается.

Comment: Не поленился сделать [тест](https://gist.github.com/zedxxx/ff8d671b2ccff3f762af7bd32fb19863) - и всё работает без ошибок. Тестировал в Delphi 10.4.2 и 11.2 под Win8.1.

Comment: И `fmShareExclusive` нужно указывать в `Mode`, а не `Rights` параметре (последний, [согласно справке](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.Classes.TFileStream.Create), под виндой просто игнорируется): `TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenReadWrite or fmShareExclusive);`

Comment: @zed Тогда всё ещё чудесатее - получается, загвоздка не в Delphi, а в системе или железе (файл на внешнем USB-диске). При этом FARом он смотрится нормально и построчно из Delphi (readln как текстовый файл) читается с начала, хоть и медленно. За fmShareExclusive - спасибо, не знал и не обращал внимания.